# Do eigenfunctions of elliptic operator form basis of $H^k(M)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

We know that the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on a compact manifold $M$ form a countable basis of $H^1(M)$. If $L$ is a $2k$-order elliptic operator, do the eigenfunctions of $L$ form a basis for $H^k(M)$? References/more detail would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: An interesting question. You meant "eigenfunctions of $L$", of course. By the way, since this is your 8th question here, maybe you could create a registered account. Access to unregistered (cookie-based) accounts is frequently lost with the cookie.

Comment: Note for readers: this was crossposted at MathOverflow, where a nice answer demonstrating that the answer is no in the general case. 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124147/do-eigenfunctions-of-elliptic-operator-form-basis-of-hkm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, if your operator is self-adjoint and coercive in the sense that
$$
\langle Lu,u\rangle \geq \alpha \|u\|_{H^k}^2 - C \|u\|_{L^2}^2,
$$
where $\alpha>0$.
This includes in particular strongly elliptic operators.

More generally, let $V$ and $H$ be Hilbert spaces, with the compact and dense embedding $V\hookrightarrow H$. 
We embed $H$ into $V'$ through the identification $H\eqsim H'$.
Let $L:V\to V'$ be a bounded linear operator satisfying
$$
\langle Lu,v\rangle = \langle u,Lv\rangle,
\qquad\textrm{for}\quad u,v\in V,
$$
and
$$
\langle Lu,u\rangle \geq \alpha \|u\|_{V}^2 - C \|u\|_{H}^2,
\qquad\textrm{for}\quad u\in V,
$$
with $\alpha>0$. Then

- By the Riesz representation theorem, $L+C\,\mathrm{id}:V\to V'$ is invertible.
- The inverse $R=(L+C\,\mathrm{id})^{-1}|_{H}$, restricted to $H$, as an operator $R:H\to H$, is compact.
- There is an orthonormal basis $\{u_n\}$ of $H$, consisting of the eigenvectors of $L$. This is an application of the spectral theory of compact operators.
- The eigenvalues are real and of finite multiplicity, and satisfy $\lambda_n> -C$ and $\lambda_n\to\infty$ (follows from the Hilbert-Schmidt theory). This and the preceding item can also be derived directly working with $L$ by variational methods.
- The functions $\{u_n\}$ form also a basis of $V$, which is orthogonal with respect to the inner product $\langle L\cdot,\cdot\rangle + C\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{H}$.

Let me elaborate on the last point a bit since this seems to be the heart of the question. The orthogonality follows from
$$
\langle Lu_n,u_m\rangle + C\langle u_n,u_m\rangle_{H} 
= \langle \lambda_nu_n,u_m\rangle + C\delta_{nm}
= (\lambda+C)\delta_{nm}.
$$
Completeness of $\{u_n\}$ in $V$ follows similarly from the completeness of $\{u_n\}$ in $H$. Letting $v\in V$, we have
$$
\langle Lu_n,v\rangle + C\langle u_n,v\rangle_{H} 
= \langle \lambda_nu_n,v\rangle + C\langle u_n,v\rangle_{H}
= (\lambda_n+C) \langle u_n,v\rangle_{H}.
$$
So if $v$ is orthogonal to each $u_n$ with respect to the new inner product in $V$ then $v=0$.

Comment: Awesome answer. What you write is clear to me, but do you know if I can find this in some reference so I can cite it? Thanks.

Comment: @michael_faber: I think you can find it in the first volume of Eberhard Zeidler's *Applied functional analysis* (Springer's AMS vol. 108), or in William McLean's *Strongly elliptic systems and boundary integral equations*.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find these books sadly. A question: to show $R$ is compact: $R:V' \to V$ is bounded by bounded inverse theorem, so a bounded set in $H$ maps to a bounded set in $V$ by continuity. By compact embedding of $V \subset H$, we have compactness. Is this correct?

Comment: @michael_faber: Yes, this is correct. But remember to apply the bounded inverse theorem on $H$, as we are talking about $R:H\to V$, which is the *restriction* of the inverse of $L+C\,\mathrm{id}$ to $H$.

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit confused about the third bullet point. We know $R:H \to H$ is compact, but how does this imply that L is compact (which we need to say that its eigenfunctions are a basis for $H$)? I thought we could use an idea like saying $R:H \to H$ is invertible but it's not since it's compact.

Comment: @michael_faber: You would apply the theorem to $R$, and then run a simple argument to conclude that the eigenfunctions of $R$ and $L$ are the same, and the eigenvalues of $R$ and $L$ are related.

Comment: I appreciate your help. BTW I posted this on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124147/do-eigenfunctions-of-elliptic-operator-form-basis-of-hkm
There is one answer there FYI.

Comment: @michael_faber: Thanks! That was an interesting answer, and provides a reference for this answer as well. In fact I have Wloka's book, and forgot to mention it.

Comment: There is a proof for the Laplacian in Lablee's Spectral Theory in Riemannian Geometry, p.78ff., which works on manifolds. It is easy to generalise to the operators described above. As far as I could tell, the Wloka and McLean proofs only worked for subsets of R^n.

Comment: @timur: where is $\langle (L+C)u,u\rangle \geq\alpha||u||^2$ used in the proof btw?

Comment: @MikeG: It is used in the invertibility of $L+C$ (first step).

Comment: @timur: why is that true? I mean, how to use this to show the invertibility? What I get is that once $L+C$ is invertible this gives it is bounded.

Comment: @MikeG: This property shows that L+C is an inner product. Then you apply the Riesz representation theorem.