# What is the regularity of the eigenfunctions for self-adjoint operators with non-smooth coefficients?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

There are well known results about elliptic operators, $L$,  that guarantee that an operator of order $2k$ generates a basis for $H^{k}$ on smooth domains.( See [Do eigenfunctions of elliptic operator form basis of $H^k(M)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324777/do-eigenfunctions-of-elliptic-operator-form-basis-of-hkm)).

My question is regarding the regularity of this basis.

In particular,

Given $-Lu=\partial_{j}(a^{ij}\partial_{i}u)$ a self-adjoint compact operator in $L^{2}$ if $a^{ij}\in C^{k}$ what can we say about the regularity of the eigenbasis?

What can we say if we know that the regularity of  $a^{ij}\in C^{\alpha,\beta}$ or $ H^{s}$ ?

Comment: I have edited the question now.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you write $L$ in an understandable way ? (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_operator#Definitions )

Comment: is that better?

Comment: I am happy with any results in any domain. But i would be mostly interested in say $L^{2}(M)$ with $M$ a compact manifold or a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard regularity theory for elliptic equations also handles the eigenvalue equation. See e.g. Theorem 8.13 of Gilbarg & Trudinger, which implies:

> If $a^{ij} \in C^k$, $\phi \in H^{k+2}$ and $\partial \Omega \in C^{k+2}$ then any solution of $Lu = \lambda u$ in $\Omega$ with $u = \phi$ on the boundary has regularity $u\in H^{k+2}$.

The same will hold on a compact manifold. You can apply the Sobolev embedding theorem from here to get classical regularity, but you do lose $\rm dim/2$ derivatives.

Towards the end of chapter 8 you'll find the result $a^{ij} \in C^{\alpha} \implies u\in C^{1;\alpha}$. I'm not sure there are any higher Hölder estimates that work without assuming the classical derivatives exist.

Comment: How do you get from a subset of $R^n$ to a compact manifold? If you work in a local patch away from the cut locus, your $\phi$ becomes the values of $u$, and then isn't $\phi$ only smooth if $u$ is already smooth anyway?

Comment: @1Rock: it's been a while since I was thinking about this stuff, but I think the easiest way to go is to work on manifolds the whole way through rather than trying to transplant the final result using a patch. Check out the first volume of Taylor's Partial Differential Equations, which develops the elliptic theory directly on compact Riemannian manifolds.